# Searchable Encryption in JAVA

Tags: java, cryptography, inverted-index

I am trying to implement a searchable encryption in JAVA by using the inverted index, pseudo-random function (PRF), and AES. I really can't understand the part where I need to encrypt each keyword from files with PRF. How do we implement a PRF in java? And below is the definition taught for us in class.
[image: Definitation of taught for us in class]
The outputs of PRF for those keywords are PRFsk1(bengals) = QWER, PRFsk1(packers) = ASDF, PRFsk1(steelers) = ZXCV, PRFsk1(patriots) = UIOP. Here sk1 is the secret key that is generated using AES.

Can someone please explain me the logic on how to do this? I am really stuck at this point.

Comment: You'll need to post which PRF you are using (or supposed to use).  There's no way we can guess how to make that function just from three simple examples.

Comment: Are we talking about the Song's article?

Comment: I have updated the question please check if you can provide any hits now.

Comment: See [here](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cs255/lectures/PRP-PRF.pdf) as AES